# Bootstrap - Merge Two Rows for Mobile View

Tags: mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3, merge, rows

I'm using bootstrap to create 2 rows of circles, the first row is col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1 and the second row is col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2. They are both within one container. For the mobile, I want it to be a grid of 9. Is there a way to merge the rows? Right now using col-xs-4 occurs independently I've included images below to express what I did:

[image: For desktop this is what I want:]

[image: For mobile this is what I want:]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-offset-1"></div>`